# Alter a double variable inside a lambda

Tags: java, lambda, final

I'm trying to test whether a `double` provided through a listener monotonically increases with each call.
For this, I'm keeping another `double` for comparison and update that at the end of the listener lambda:

```
double lastProgress = 0;

operator.addProgressListener(progress -> {
  assertThat(progress, greaterThanOrEqualTo(lastProgress));
  lastProgress = progress;
});
```

However, this naturally results in a compilation error (`Local variable lastProgress defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final`), since `lastProgress` is being altered.

For `long` variables, a workaround would be to use a final instance of `AtomicLong`, and set its value accordingly. For `double`s, their value could be mapped to `long` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5505512/1090166), resulting in the following code:

```
AtomicLong lastProgress = new AtomicLong(Double.doubleToLongBits(0));

operator.addProgressListener(progress -> {
  assertThat(progress, greaterThanOrEqualTo(Double.longBitsToDouble(lastProgress.get())));
  lastProgress.set(Double.doubleToLongBits(progress));
});
```

Even though this works, it's quite inconvenient and not trivial to understand what's going on.

As Java comes with no built-in class like `AtomicDouble`, **is there a convenient way of obtaining a mutuable, final object representing a `double`?**

Comment: Why not make your own DoubleWrapper with nothing but a public `double` field?

Comment: Have you considered the [`MutableDouble`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/mutable/MutableDouble.html) that comes with Apache Commons?

Comment: There is [AtomicDouble](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AtomicDouble.html) in Guava.

Comment: @Travis: Considered, but didn't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @JoeC, kennytm: Hmm, those look useful. Maybe their existence can be considered an indicator that there's no useful alternative in the standard library.