# Thread safety for class level double variable

Tags: java, thread-safety

I have a class level double variable and I already see a problem in multi-
threading environment. Class A is called by multiple threads with different list. What is the best way to make var1 thread safe considering it s performance critical application?

```
class A {

 private double var1= 0.25

 public methodB(List<MyObj> lst){
    for (MyObj obj : lst){
     methodA (obj);
    }
 }

  public void methodA(MyObj obj){
    if(obj.getVal.equals("someString")) {
    var1= 0.15;
    }
  //do something with var1
 } // end of method
} // end of class
```

Will volatile keyword work in this case?

Comment: I depends on the actual usecase. Like what operations do you want to be atomic and what don't have to be. The simplest option would be to make `methodA` synchronized.

Comment: We need a lot more detail.  What kind of application?  Why is it multi-threaded?  What is the nature of class A?  Is it a data class?  A data repository?

Comment: I need a separate copy of var1 for each thread. If a thread changes the value of var1, it should not be reflected in thread2. @Amongalen.

Comment: Separate copy within a *single instance* of `A`?  That sounds like a job for [ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html).  Or, just have each thread make its own instance of `A`.

Answer (score 1):

Java provides [atomic package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) that support lock-free thread-safe programming on single variables. This is especially useful when you want to use some primitive as global variable but also care about thread-safety.

Now, this classes from this package will help you but it doesn't provide a direct `AtomicDouble` class, but it tells you how to achieve that, see below note from the documentation:

> Atomic classes are not general purpose replacements for
>   java.lang.Integer and related classes. They do not define methods such
>   as equals, hashCode and compareTo. (Because atomic variables are
>   expected to be mutated, they are poor choices for hash table keys.)
>   Additionally, classes are provided only for those types that are
>   commonly useful in intended applications. For example, there is no
>   atomic class for representing byte. In those infrequent cases where
>   you would like to do so, you can use an AtomicInteger to hold byte
>   values, and cast appropriately. You can also hold floats using
>   Float.floatToRawIntBits(float) and Float.intBitsToFloat(int)
>   conversions, and doubles using Double.doubleToRawLongBits(double) and
>   Double.longBitsToDouble(long) conversions.

---

---

Do read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505460/java-is-there-no-atomicfloat-or-atomicdouble) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Making var1 `volatile` will force a load from main memory and not from cache.

```java
class A {

 private volatile double  var1= 0.25

  public void methodA(){
    if(somethigIsTrue) {
    var1= 0.15;
    }
  //do something with var1
 } // end of method
} //
```

Refer to the answer to this question regarding performance concerns:
[Is volatile expensive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633866/is-volatile-expensive)